# How to resolve exceptions while migrating bot state data to SQL in Botframework

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

As per new update, I am trying to export my bot state data to my local SQL. I am using v3.14.1.1 of Microsoft.Bot.Builder. I followed the steps explained [Here](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/26/saving-state-sql-dotnet/). I updated the connection string as following:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="BotDataContextConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=BER-NB-005\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=JoeBotState;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;Integrated Security=True" /></connectionStrings>
```

I updated my Global.asax as following:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        BotConfig.UpdateConversationContainer();

    }
}

public static class BotConfig
{
    public static void UpdateConversationContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new DialogModule());
        var store = new SqlBotDataStore("BotDataContextConnectionString");

        builder
            .Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(c.ResolveKeyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(typeof(ConnectorStore)), CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.LastWriteWins))
            .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
            .AsSelf()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
    }
}
```

And i added following three files as in [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/tree/master/blog-samples/CSharp/AzureSql-StateClient/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.AzureSql/SqlStateService) example in SqlStateService folder

- SqlBotDataContext.cs
- SqlBotDataEntity.cs
- SqlBotDataStore.cs

Now when i run the command **PM> enable-migrations** it throws me following exception:

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception.

Complete stack trace is in the attached image as following.

[image: Stack Trace]

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you created the JoeBotState database on BER-NB-005\SQLEXPRESS ?  You can find a script to create it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/AzureSql-CreateTable.sql

Comment: Also, if you are using BotBuilder-Azure, it is not necessary to re-create the SqlBotData classes in your solution.  The blog you linked is a little dated.  BotBuilder-Azure now contains the classes to use Sql Server as a state service.  Please refer to: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AzureSql